# Can I use the released data on AER and JPE in my own research without permission?

Tags: microeconomics, public-economics, empirical-evidence, data

I don't think JPE has suggested a specific license. However, the journal did say that the data policy is adopted from American Economic Review (AER). AER did suggest a license of Creative Commons Attribution International 4.0 (CC-BY). 
That license allows reuse of data without asking permission (I just have to cite it). So my question is, may I also use the data released by JPE without asking permission?

One economic professor said if the data is specified as "replication data", then you cannot reuse it without permission.

The data is not specified as a "replication"

Comment: Yes you can always use others' work so long as you cite it, don't pass it off as your own work, don't just copy-paste it, and actually build on it.

Comment: @KennyLJ I am using their data to do my own analysis, which is very different from them. Not sure if this is violating any copyright issues